# How to find and print specific file paths with exclusions?

Tags: find, osx, ls, pwd

**Goal:** Output .txt file with the full directory path, including name, of all .html files ***except*** for those with "txt" or "text" in the .html file name.

I found the following line gives me the desired .txt file with the file's full directory path. The only problem is that it gives me ALL of the folder's contents:

```
ls -d "$PWD"/* > fileList.txt
```

**Example Results:**

```
/Users/username/Desktop/WebsiteFiles/notes.txt
/Users/username/Desktop/WebsiteFiles/index.html
/Users/username/Desktop/WebsiteFiles/index-TEXT.html
/Users/username/Desktop/WebsiteFiles/answers.html
/Users/username/Desktop/WebsiteFiles/answers_txt.html
/Users/username/Desktop/WebsiteFiles/image.jpg
/Users/username/Desktop/WebsiteFiles/image2.jpg
/Users/username/Desktop/WebsiteFiles/about.html
/Users/username/Desktop/WebsiteFiles/about_TXT.html
/Users/username/Desktop/WebsiteFiles/contact.html
/Users/username/Desktop/WebsiteFiles/contact_text.html
/Users/username/Desktop/WebsiteFiles/images
```

**Desired Results:**

```
/Users/username/Desktop/WebsiteFiles/index.html
/Users/username/Desktop/WebsiteFiles/answers.html
/Users/username/Desktop/WebsiteFiles/about.html
/Users/username/Desktop/WebsiteFiles/contact.html
```

### **Experimenting:**

I'm fairly new to using the command line. I've been experimenting trying to figure this stuff out. I found that the following **find** helps find all .html files:

```
find . -iname '*.html'
```

When used on the parent directory it will give me all .html files but not the full directory path, example result:

```
./index.html
./index-TEXT.html
./answers.html
./answers_txt.html
./about.html
./about_TXT.html
./contact.html
./contact_text.html
```

I'm not familiar enough with the parameters or assembling these commands and haven't been successful in getting a print of just the .html files without the ones with any of the variation of "text" in the name.

I have a **ton** of files to find with this and need that .txt file with the full paths. I want to understand this stuff so please provide detailed responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` will output the found names with the path that you give it, so you can start building the command with

```
find /Users/username/Desktop/WebsiteFiles
```

or, if that's where you're located currently,

```
find "$PWD"
```

Next, we restrict the found names to only names matching `*.html`:

```
find "$PWD" -type f -name '*.html'
```

If you have both `*.html` and `*.HTML` (or `*.hTmL`) files, and if you want to include these, then change `-name` to `-iname` (which does case-insensitive name matching).

I also added `-type f` on the off chance that you have any *directories* with names matching `*.html` (we don't want to see these in the result). `-type f` restricts the name to those of regular files only.

Then you wanted to remove particular filenames from the result.  Names containing the strings `txt` or `text` (up or down case). This can be done through negating the `-iname` test with `!`:

```
find "$PWD" -type f -name '*.html' ! -iname "*txt*" ! -iname "*text*"
```

And there you have it.

Each "predicate" (`-type f` etc.) acts like a test against the names in the given directory, and there's an implicit logical AND between the tests.  If all tests pass, the name is printed.

Running in a temporary directory on my machine, with the files that you have in your directory (just empty files for testing):

```
$ ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel      0 Sep 26 17:47 about.html
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel      0 Sep 26 17:47 about_TXT.html
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel      0 Sep 26 17:47 answers.html
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel      0 Sep 26 17:47 answers_txt.html
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel      0 Sep 26 17:47 contact.html
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel      0 Sep 26 17:47 contact_text.html
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    596 Sep 26 17:46 files
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel      0 Sep 26 17:47 image.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel      0 Sep 26 17:47 image2.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel      0 Sep 26 17:47 images
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel      0 Sep 26 17:47 index-TEXT.html
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel      0 Sep 26 17:47 index.html
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel      0 Sep 26 17:47 notes.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  10240 Sep 26 19:11 test.tar

$ find "$PWD" -type f -name '*.html' ! -iname "*txt*" ! -iname "*text*"
/tmp/shell-ksh.p56GA7BA/index.html
/tmp/shell-ksh.p56GA7BA/answers.html
/tmp/shell-ksh.p56GA7BA/about.html
/tmp/shell-ksh.p56GA7BA/contact.html
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. And thanks for explaining. I was able to add the output of > fileList.txt to the end and it did exactly what I wanted.